# Why does the same MySQL query take way longer for a different ID?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, time

This is the query I use to fetch and display data for my profiles pages. Each category has its own tables because they are constantly being added to by users. I'm new to MYSQL and must be doing something wrong because the query takes 0.7 seconds for one provider (id=56), but 27 seconds (!!!) for provider with id=164. I thought they both had about the same amount of data tied to them, so I can't figure out why the one is taking so long.

Since I'm new to MySQL, I don't know if my long query is normal, or if there's a shorter, easier way to do it that I'm not realizing. However, it works just fine on all my providers except the one.

I did an EXPLAIN on both and the only difference was that the "Type" listed for the slow query had 4 "ALL"s and the faster one only had 2, same for the column that says "Extra," - the slow query had 4 that said "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)" and the fast had 2. I'm not sure what those mean, but that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Appreciate your help!

Changing/removing Concat and Distinct doesn't help.

```
SELECT `providers`.`id`,
`providers`.`provider_first_name`, 
`providers`.`provider_last_name`,
`providers`.`p_date_added`,
`degrees`.`degree_type`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `degrees`.`degree_type` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 
all_degrees,
`specialties`.`specialty`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `specialties`.`specialty` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 
all_specialties,
`locations`.`city`, `locations`.`state`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(`locations`.`city`, ', ', 
`locations`.`state`)
ORDER BY `locations`.`city`
SEPARATOR '<br>'
) AS all_locations,
`practices`.`practice_name`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `practices`.`practice_name` SEPARATOR '<br>') 
AS all_practices,
`links`.`link`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `links`.`link` SEPARATOR '<br>') AS 
all_links,
`conditions`.`condition_name`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `conditions`.`condition_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
AS all_conditions,
`reviews`.`review`, `reviews`.`star_rating`, 
`reviews`.`r_date_added`,
AVG(`reviews`.`star_rating`) AS rating
FROM `providers`
LEFT JOIN `degrees` ON `providers`.`id` = `degrees`.`prov_id`
LEFT JOIN `specialties` ON `providers`.`id` = 
`specialties`.`prov_id`
LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `providers`.`id` = `locations`.`prov_id`
LEFT JOIN `practices` ON `providers`.`id` = `practices`.`prov_id`
LEFT JOIN `links` ON `providers`.`id` = `links`.`prov_id`
LEFT JOIN `conditions` ON `providers`.`id` = `conditions`.`prov_id`
LEFT JOIN `reviews` ON `providers`.`id` = `reviews`.`prov_id`
WHERE `id`= {$providerid}
GROUP BY `id`
```

Comment: okay when I select the data without distinct to see how much data is connected to each ID, there is a significant amount more (almost 3x) for the slow ID, but I'm not sure why, something about how it's looping through the data? They should have roughly the same amount of data connected to them...

Comment: It's crazy to me to use GROUP_CONCAT in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode-Implode -- The `JOINs` explode the number of rows, then the `GROUP BY` implodes down to very few (apparently only one).

To avoid that, move the `LEFT JOINs` into the `SELECT`.  For example:

```
SELECT ...
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `degrees`.`degree_type` SEPARATOR ', ') AS all_degrees,
    ...
    LEFT JOIN  `degrees`  ON `providers`.`id` = `degrees`.`prov_id`
    ...
```

-->

```
SELECT ...
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `degree_type` SEPARATOR ', ')
              FROM `degrees`
              WHERE `providers`.`id` = `prov_id`
        ) AS all_degrees,
     ...
```

And the final `GROUP BY id` can be removed.

At this point, the `DISTINCT` is probably redundant; try removing it.

Comment: This worked great. My new problem though is if I use this same structure on my search engine query, I have to append additional parts to the query if (and only if) they enter something in a particular search field. Usually I've just done $query .= " AND `city` LIKE :city" but now that these are inside these SELECT parentheses, and I can't figure out how to add them only when the field is filled in (I've posted that question here if you have any thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194881/how-to-get-query-to-ignore-empty-search-fields-in-my-search-engine/57195152#57195152

Comment: @mb9393 - You need PHP (or other language) code to construct the query based on the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN query`

**ALL** means it is equivalent to full scan of table.  To prevent this is add index on your table. Add index on a column which you normally use on searching or connecting certain data.

**ROWS** represents the cardinality of records whithin the indexed records. Smaller the number the better.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html

Reading more about EXPLAIN really helps.